# How to point to the airflow unittest.cfg?

Tags: airflow

Airflow creates a `unittest.cfg` file in the `AIRFLOW_HOME` environment variable path.

My question is: how can I point to `unittest.cfg` in the same why that I point to the `airflow.cfg` via the environment variable `AIRFLOW_CONFIG`?

The reason why I want to do this is because I don't want to have any config files in the `AIRFLOW_HOME` directory.

Also, if anyone knows better, could you please explain what is the `unittest.cfg` is for as there is no documentation I could find on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unittest.cfg` test configuration file is the [default configuration file](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.5/airflow/configuration.py#L558,L561) used when Airflow is running in test mode.

Test mode can be activated by setting the [`unit_test_mode` configuration](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.5/docs/howto/use-test-config.rst) option in `airflow.cfg` or `AIRFLOW__CORE__UNIT_TEST_MODE` environment variable to `True` .

The configuration values in test configuration file overwrite those in `airflow.cfg` in runtime when test mode is activated.

```py
# Source: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.5/airflow/configuration.py#L558,L561
def get_airflow_test_config(airflow_home):
    if 'AIRFLOW_TEST_CONFIG' not in os.environ:
        return os.path.join(airflow_home, 'unittests.cfg')
    return expand_env_var(os.environ['AIRFLOW_TEST_CONFIG'])
```

The `AIRFLOW_TEST_CONFIG` environment variable can be set to the path of your test configuration file.